# How to pass data to constructor from component in Blazor

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, components, blazor

Im calling component from razor file as this:

`<BaseTable></BaseTable>`

but has exception from request because component not have parameterless constructor:

```
public class BaseTable:ComponentBase
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public BaseTable(HttpClient httpClient)
      {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
      }
}
```

How to access component's ctor from .razor page or from caller component?
Edit: Error still contiuning..

Comment: You will want to `@inject` the dependency. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-a-service-in-a-component)

Comment: I want access _httpClient from class code. Not in .razor page.

Comment: that makes it available to the class.

Comment: _httpClient is null from class. How to pass injected client or how to DI in class?

Answer (score 2):

In this case I Recommend you to Inject the HttpClient in top of Blazor Component:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
```

Then in code you can use it as you want like

```
@code{
    private IService service;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {     
        service = new Service(Http);      
    }
       
}
```